# Как корректно приостановить дочерний процесс в Linux

Tags: linux, c, процесс, fork

Всем привет!
Используемая ос - Ubuntu22/Alpine Linux. 
Столкнулся с проблемой приостановки дочернего процесса в Linux. 
Есть два процесса: родительский, который мониторит некоторые файлики, и дочерний, в котором запускается оболочка(`system("/bin/bash")`).
В какой-то момент родительскому процессу нужно пообщаться с юзером через консольку, но для этого нужно приостановить процесс оболочки, чтобы они не конфликтовали за ввод-вывод в одной консоли. Нашел способ вызывать `kill(pid, SIGSTOP)`, но получаю ошибку

> sudo: mon_handle_sigchld: waitpid: Нет дочерних процессов

которая печатается без остановки.
Подозреваю, что это из-за того, что вызов оболочки порождает дочерний процесс в уже  дочернем для меня процессе.
Подскажите, как с этим бороться? Еще одно окно консоли создавать нельзя, т.к. исполняемый файлик будет исполняться кроме Ubuntu, так же еще и на одноконсольной Alpine Linux. Нужно добиться приостановки процесса оболочки, чтобы основной родительский процесс мог отработать с юзером и запустить обратно дочерний с оболочкой.

Answer (score 0):

Я запускал шелл в новой pty и копировал содержимое в основной. Копирование легко приостановить по какому-нибудь семафору. Приостановка в этом случае не обязательна.